# How to validate xml string in jquery?

Tags: xml, jquery-validate

I m working on a project which requires to edit the xml tags via jquery.
Before I save the xml in the form of string, I wanted to validate if the xml tags matched properly but on the client side with jquery.
Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please accept an answer if you can

Answer (score 4):

I was looking to validate a form text input as XML using the excellent jQuery [Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin, this ended up doing the trick:

```
$.validator.addMethod('XML', function(value, element){
    var isXml;
    if(!this.optional(element)){
        try{
            isXml = $.parseXML(value);
        }catch(e){
            isXml = false;
        }
    }
    return isXml !== false;
}, 'This is not valid XML');
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a [`$.parseXML()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) since 1.5.