# How to find invalid unclosed XML tags in a variable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, regex

I want to find unclosed XML tags in a variable or a text box.

```
var xml = "<name>supun</name><age>23<year>1111</year>";
```

so age has no end tag, I wanna find that tag

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530604/how-to-validate-xml-string-in-jquery) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073972/xml-validation-using-jquery-parsexml-data). If they will not help you, you can search in Google for some libraries/plugins doing this. It it will also not help, you can do it manually, by parsing string character by character, adding open tags in stack and popping from stack when close tag is found.

Comment: You need to specify the requirements more precisely. For example, do you also want to find a start tag whose end tag is misplaced (not properly nested)? What information do you want back - just the name of the unclosed tag, or its location as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below function for handling invalid xml as follows

```js
var xt="",h3OK=1
function checkErrorXML(x)
{
xt=""
h3OK=1
checkXML(x)
}

function checkXML(n)
{
var l,i,nam
nam=n.nodeName
if (nam=="h3")
 {
 if (h3OK==0)
  {
  return;
  }
 h3OK=0
 }
if (nam=="#text")
 {
 xt=xt + n.nodeValue + "\n"
 }
l=n.childNodes.length
for (i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
 checkXML(n.childNodes[i])
 }
}        
function validateXML(xml)
    {
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
      {
      var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async=false;
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
    
      if(xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode!=0)
        {
        txt="Error Code: " + xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode + "\n";
        txt=txt+"Error Reason: " + xmlDoc.parseError.reason;
        txt=txt+"Error Line: " + xmlDoc.parseError.line;
        alert(txt);
        }
      else
        {
        alert("No errors found");
        }
      }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
    var parser=new DOMParser();
    var text=xml;
    var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
    if (xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror").length>0)
        {
        checkErrorXML(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("parsererror")[0]);
        alert(xt)
        }
      else
        {
        alert("No errors found");
        }
      }
    else
      {
      alert('Your browser cannot handle this script');
      }
    }

var xml="<xml><name>supun</name><age>23<year>1111</year></xml>";
validateXML(xml);
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_errors.asp

Comment: I don't see PHP tag in question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one small regexp hack:

```
var str = "<name>supun</name><age>23<year>1111</year>";

function getInvalidTags(str)
{
    // remove text between XML tags:
    var noText = str.replace(/>[^<>]*</g, "><");
    var prev = noText;
    var next = "";
    // while something changed remove <any></any> pairs
    while (prev != (next = prev.replace(/<([^<>]*)( [^<>]*)?><\/\1>/g, "")))
        prev = next;
    return prev;
}
console.log(getInvalidTags(str));
```

Note that it doesn't support attributes but it easily can be extended to support them.

**UPDATE**: Updated to support attributes.

Comment: xml like this does't find:

<p cid="#P1_002"></p>

<p>
   <prism_object>
</p>

<maintext></maintext>

Comment: Try again. I've added support attributes